# Проверить содержит ли имя переменной определенные символы

Tags: переменные, c++

Функцией получаю имя, как можно проверить содержание этого имени на такие символы как: ''|;"\//][

Comment: Вы, случаем не из PHP?

>ну, если ник у ТС заканчивается не web, шансы довольно велики :)

а я уже по тегам убедился :)

Comment: @mega: ну, если ник у ТС заканчивается не web, шансы довольно велики :)
@avengerweb: добро пожаловать в мир C++!

Comment: >добро пожаловать в мир C++!

в мир, который весьма жесток к эмигрантам из php)))

Comment: Я уж понял :)

Comment: @DreamChild Вы излишне многословны. Проще сказать

     в мир, который весьма жесток

Comment: @avengerweb: вы задаётесь неправильным вопросом. Если допустим потеря в производительности составляет 500%, одна версия выполняется за 100 наносекунд, а другая за 600, нужно ли вам об этом думать? Если вы вычисляете значение сотни тысяч раз раз в секунду, да. Если нет -- вряд ли.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте [`find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of):

```
if (s.find_first_of("'|;\"\\/][") != std::string::npos)
{
    // gotcha!
```

---

Выношу из дискуссии в комментариях.

Как верно замечает [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp) (спасибо!), реализация `find_first_of` может быть медленнее, чем более старая библиотечная функции [`std::strpbrk`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strpbrk). Если у вас возможна просадка по производительности из-за частого вызова `find_first_of`, попробуйте так:

```
if (strpbrk(s.c_str(), "'|;\"\\/]["))
{
    // gotcha!
```

Для `wchar_t`-строк используйте "широкий" аналог [`wcspbrk`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcspbrk).

Comment: Тут циклом? он проверяет первый символ?

Comment: Не, никаких циклов, этот код ищет все символы во всей строке `s`.

Comment: Все спасибо понял

Comment: @avengerweb: Пожалуйста!

Comment: Обратите внимание, что может срываться за одним словом [find_first_of](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18473/find_first_of-A-performance-pitfall-among-the-STL#A40)

И не забудьте посмотрите на графики в конце странички.

Comment: @avp: вручную было бы не быстрее. Иначе разработчики языка сделали бы так, как быстрее.

---
Прочитав статью, беру свои слова назад. Тем не менее, оптимизация библиотечной функции кажется мне микрооптимизацией.

Comment: @VladD, а зачем вручную? strpbrk() из Сишной библиотеки IMHO всюду должна работать.

Вы на результаты посмотрите.

Comment: @avp: небольшая разница в семантике есть: `strpbrk` не допускает встроенных в строку нулей, в то время как `find_first_of` ведёт себя как полагается в C++. Тем не менее, микрооптимизация же? Пусть разработчики STL сделают специализацию шаблона.

---
Обновлю всё же ответ.

Comment: А примерное процентное соотношение в потери производительности какое?